# 5V Input and Output interfacing with 3.3V GPIO

Tags: npn, level-shifting, pnp, logic-level

I have a device (a motor drive) with 5V logic. My controller is 3.3V.
I draw the two circuits. The right sides are fixed in the device.
I have some exact questions about calculations.

-`Q` - What to look when selection a transistor for this applications? Some rule of thumb, or most common for this logic level shifting?

**The input:**

[image: NPN ON OUTPUT]

-`Rb` - let's say - for a ZXTN4240F? Will a 1k good? (3.3V/1000R=~3mA base current, right?)

-`Rc` - good around 200R? How to determinate the proper size? (5V/200R=25mA, right?). Can a 1k more efficient, and less power compulsion?

-If I switch my circuit pull up (`Rc`=200R) rail to 3.3V, that means (3.3V/200R=12.5=16mA) collector current?

-How to determinate `Rc` power? P=3.3*3.3/200=50mW?

-How to get the voltage drop across `Q`?

**The output:**

[image]

-What will be the power requirements for Re?

-Emitter current will be 5V/Re?

-Can I pull the GPIO input to 3.3V rail instead of 5V? If yes what will change (currents and power compulsion)?

Comment: In your first circuit, if there is already a 5k pullup on the receiving end there is usually no need to provide another pullup on the transmitter end. (Or... little need, anyway.) My first question is why do you think it may be needed? (Figure to start there before discussing the 2nd circuit.)

Comment: The first thing you need to check before doing anything is to check if 5V motor controller input can work with TTL level signals, so it will work with 3.3V output, and also check if your 3.3V input is 5V tolerant.

Comment: The motor controller works with 5V TTL, and the GPIO is 3.3V LVTTL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jonk suggested in his [comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/623746/5v-input-and-output-interfacing-with-3-3v-gpio#comment1647855_623746) you can simply omit Rc as the chip (or device) already has a pull-up, unless the manual/datasheet strongly suggests you to use one.

**Determining Rb:** Basically Q will be used as a switch so it needs to be saturated. For saturation, I use a practical formula (not a formula actually, comes from experience): Check the BJT's datasheet and use the one tenth of its minimum h<sub>FE</sub> as I<sub>C</sub>/I<sub>B</sub> ratio. And calculate Rb for this ratio. This will force the BJT into saturation. For example, if minimum current gain is given as 200 then select a base current of one twentieth of the collector current. In your case, the collector current will be 5V/5k = 1 mA (because there's no need to put an external Rc here) so the Rb should be calculated for a base current of 50 microamps.

**Voltage drop across Q:** Check the datasheet for this as it's given as V<sub>CEsat</sub> - remember you'll be using the BJT in saturation. Don't expect exactly the same voltage given but in your case it's not generally going to be higher than 0.1 or 0.2 VDC.

---

For the output section, same things apply: Q needs to be used in saturation.

> -Can I pull the GPIO input to 3.3V rail instead of 5V?

That is what you "must" do unless it's indicated in the datasheet that the GPIOs are 5V-tolerant. You can simply tie the top end of Re to 3V3 for your application.

The current flowing through Re when Q is in saturation will be approximately 3V/Re (neglecting the saturation drop across emitter and collector -- again, it's not generally higher than 0.1-0.2 VDC). This current should be high enough so that the GPIO's input current can be neglected (e.g. if GPIO draws 10uA then 500uA collector/emitter current should be enough). And Rb should be high enough to keep its losses minimum. For most applications, 3.3k to 10k is enough. You can calculate the power loss for saturated Q.