# Level shifter circuit max current output

Tags: level-shifting

I want to use the BSs138 as level shifter between 3.3v and 5v as shown below.
[image]

With this setup one can get max 0.33mA on 3.3V side when level high is applied to right side. My question is if the current requirement on attached load to 3.3V side is high, can we reduce 10K to lets say 330ohms to acquire 10mA output?

Comment: It depends if the high voltage side can sink that current or not. If you need that amount of current, you would not use a bi-directional logic level shifter for any high power loads, only for logic signals requiring bi-directionality.

Comment: You mean the current is taken from high voltage side connected source and not the VL power supply?

Comment: @IjazAhmad Justme means that you'd use an entirely different circuit - one that's not bidirectional. What are you actually trying to do? Why do you need 10mA?

Comment: @Justme thanks for the reply. I am using arduino with a target of 3.3v and estimated 10mA consumption. Arduino pins can provide upto 40mA but we need a level shifter. So for that I need this circuit.

Comment: It is clear that you need level shifting with 10mA drive ability, but this circuit may be poor fit to what you want to do - but you did not say what exactly you want to do to know if this will work or not.

Comment: Simple GPIO toggle to turn ON/OFF some transistor switches on interfaces target PCB. May you recommend any other circuit?

Comment: What do you think of this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/623746/5v-input-and-output-interfacing-with-3-3v-gpio